# How can I activate a conda environment whenever I start a Powershell session in a project folder?

Tags: powershell, anaconda, conda

I use [Anaconda environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) to manage my Python installations.
I have my Python projects organized in folders; every folder contains the code for one project and a file `environments.yml` that specifies the packages that a conda environment should have to run that specific Python project.

Often I start working on a project as follows:

1. I navigate to the project folder (in Total Commander, but that's irrelevant I think).
2. I look at the contents of the `environment.yml` file to see what conda environment needs to be used for this project
3. I start a Powershell session in the folder and activate the conda environment in Powershell with `conda activate some_env_name`.
4. I start the rest my programs, e.g. `jupyter lab` or `spyder`.

I feel the steps 2 and 3 should somehow be automatic, but how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out various methods I settled on a function in my `profile.ps1` file that gets triggered every time I start a new powershell session.

The function reads the environment name from the `environment.yml` file and tries to activate that environment:

```
function conda_here {
  $first_line = Get-Content -Head 1 environment.yml  # This returns "name: conda_env_name"
  $env_name = $first_line.Split(": ")[-1]  # This splits it into an array of [name, : , conda_env_name] and takes the last element
  try {
    conda activate $env_name
  } catch {
    Write-Host "Tried to activate environment $env_name, but failed." -ForeGroundColor Red
  }
}
```

To let that function trigger on every powershell start I added the following after the function definition:

```
# Activate a conda environment when started in a dir with a .conda-env file
if ( Test-Path environment.yml ){
  conda_here 
}
```

Now whenever I start a powershell session in a folder with an `environment.yml` file the corresponding conda environment gets activated automatically.

Comment: You can accept your own answer

Comment: [In 2 days after posting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) I probably will (if no better solution comes up).